# undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass semantic_form_for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, csv, import, formtastic

I am trying to upload a file to be parsed for attributes using semantic_form_for and I cannot seem to get it to work, although from what I've read it should be. I have been at this for a while now and cant seem to get anything to work.

Here is my view.haml:

```
= semantic_form_for(@user, :url => import_users_path, :html => {:multipart => true} ) do |f|
        = f.inputs :id => 'inputs' do
          = f.input :filename, :as => :file
        %br
        %br
        = f.actions do
          = f.action :submit, :label => 'BULK UPLOAD'
```

and the users controller import function:

```
 def import
    myfile = params[:filename]

    CSV.foreach(myfile.path, headers: true) do |row|
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      @user.name = row['Name']
      @user.email = row['Email']
      @user.save
    end
    redirect_to users_url 
  end
```

For whatever reason, the file does not seem to be passed into the import function.  It worked fine with form_for, but not semantic_form_for which is what i need to try and use.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: your `import_users_path ` is correct, you sure? Does it take any parameter? Can you check?

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam definitely right, this was working with `= form_tag import_users_path, multipart: true do` before, I'm just switching it over to semantic form for now

Comment: can you post the full error stacktrace? seems like something is wrong with the url

Comment: can you run this? `rake routes | grep import` and show the output?

Comment: Can you please try my solution and let me know if that works? Just one line change in your controller's import action: `@user = User.new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `myfile = params[:filename]` to `myfile = params[:user][:file]`in your controller's import method:

```
def import
  myfile = params[:user][:file]

  CSV.foreach(myfile.path, headers: true) do |row|
    @user = User.new
    @user.name = row['Name']
    @user.email = row['Email']
    @user.save
  end
  redirect_to users_url
end
```

Comment: This results in the same error on the CSV.foreach line.  Also, this method is creating multiple users, so wouldn't creating the User at the top only create one new user? My controller worked as expected with form_for, not with semantic_form_for, so I don't think it is something that needs to be changed with users here, it is the myfile.path which is coming up null

Comment: Please show your full stack trace and the `params` hash when you post the form.

Comment: oh i got it. Change : `params[:filename]` to `params[:file]` as you used: `as: file`

Comment: same result, ugh, thought that was it

Comment: I know that works, I was just attempting to use semantic_form_for and was wondering why it was not working.  I used form_tag originally (as I said in the comments above) but was trying to switch it over to semantic_form_for as it has been used throughout my app and couldn't understand why it's not working because form_tag worked flawlessly

Comment: ok, if you want to use, semantic_form, then use `f.file_field :file` instead of `f.input :filename, :as => :file `
When, uploading files, you should use `file_field` or `file_tag` NOT `input`

Comment: same result, I had used that at first then switched over to this method hoping to change it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87615/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-seanscal).

Answer (score 0):

It's looking like some url issue

```
<% semantic_form_for :post, Post.new, :url => posts_path do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

look on it http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/formtastic/0.9.10/Formtastic/SemanticFormHelper

Try this form will open in user new action right? then ...

```
def new 
 @user = User.new 
end


def import
  CSV.foreach(myfile.path, headers: true) do |row|
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.name = row['Name']
    @user.email = row['Email']
    @user.save
   end
   redirect_to users_url 
end


<%= semantic_form_for(@user, :url => import_users_path(@user)) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: this just results in `wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)` when i use it with my semantic_form_for

Comment: could you run rake routes | grep import  and put the routes here

Comment: `import_users POST   /users/import(.:format)                            users#import` @Arv

Comment: @seanscal I have added one more code please check it , because similar is working for me.